# Why auto iteration in C++ cannot perform operation on the element it points to?

Tags: c++11

I just spent ~2 on trying to figure out a bug introduced to my code due to the usage of `auto` iteration for containers. I started using it couple of days ago, without doing much background check, just because I found it easier to write.

I have the following map: `std::map<int, VectorList>`, where `VectorList` is just a `typedef std::vector<double> VectorList`.

I wanted to perform `.clear()` operation on the `std::vector<double>` of the `VectorList`.

I tried the following:

```
std::map<int, VectorList> map;
for(auto elem : map)
{
    elem.second.clear();

}
```

and it did not work. The clear operation was not being performed on the `VectorList`. However when I was performing `.empty()` check on it, it would return `True`.

Then I went back to this approach:

```
for(std::map<int, VectorList>::iterator elem = map.begin(); elem != map.end(); ++elem)
{
    elem->second.clear();
}
```

And everything worked as expected.

---

**Question:**

Why `auto` iteration does not perform the `.clear()` operation as expected? Can this be achieved with `auto` iteration at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `elem` is created *by value*. If you want to modify the value in the loop then loop using references:

```
for(auto& elem : map)
```

Comment: hah, I see... could you add a reading link in here for `auto`? 15 mins of extra reading cost me 2,5 hours of stupid debugging. (Y)

Comment: I noticed some examples with `for (auto&& i : v)` where  `std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` ... What does `auto&&` represent there, compared to your example?